# Can HiRISE photograph Starman?

Tags: spacex, mars, photography, tesla-roadster, mars-reconnaissance-orbiter

On Oct 7, 2020, according to the [latest predictions](http://www.whereisroadster.com/), the Tesla Roadster/ Starman will pass within 0.05 AU (7.4 million km). Could HiRISE image it with any success, and as anything but a dot?

Comment: If you ask could it be resolved - it will not. HiRISE has aperture 0.5 meter and the angular size of the target at distance 7.4 million kilometers will be far far beyond diffractional limit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction-limited_system#Implications_for_digital_photography

Answer (score 2):

Great question!

Using JPL's [Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi) in Observer mode one can see their predictions for apparent magnitude *as seen from Earth*, including locations on Earth that contain the word "Mars" but unfortunately not from Mars the planet. Still the information is instructive.

I've started the math for calculating apparent magnitude in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25121/12102) but have not included the dependence on the angle of illumination. It wouldn't be the same for a slowly rotating long cylinder as it would for a sphere anyway.

At 7 million km from Earth, Roadster is predicted to have an apparent magnitude of about +22. This will have a few magnitudes uncertainty, as well as *variability* as the oblong rocket-body rotates (this variability is already observed).

There are also variations of a few magnitudes due to the phase angle of illumination.

From Mars, add +1 for the increased distance to the Sun also.

HiRise is designed to see the daytime side of Mars. Right now don't know about its performance in extremely low light levels or arc-second pointing stability for long exposures, but with a (huge!) [50 cm aperture](https://www.uahirise.org/teknikos.php) there seems to be a possibility. Note that HiRise seems to be the winner for the question [What's the largest aperture telescope sent beyond the earth-moon system?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17008/12102)

[image]

**above:** From [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:MRO_HiRISE.jpg). Click for full size.

If HST's [limiting magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limiting_magnitude) is +31, then $ 2.5 \log_{10}\left(\frac{2.4^2}{0.5^2}\right)$ suggests a similarly equipped space-based telescope not looking through an atmosphere with a 0.5 meter aperture might have a limiting magnitude *in the ball park* of +27, so  I don't think this can be ruled out yet.

[image]

[image]